# Javascript handles $ key and END key , as code --> 36. How to differentiate?

Tags: javascript

I have written a Java-script function, in which I'm checking which key is pressed for the "OnKeyPress" event of a text-box.

```
if (key==35 || key==36)
       return true; // return true only if the key pressed is HOME or END.
```

.

But, if a user enters key # or $, then also the above function returns true. As # stands for 35 and & stands for 36. Which is incorrect as per my requirement.

My question, is how can I differentiate between these two types in java-script.

Please help.

here is the entire code:-

Aspx:-

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server" MaxLength="255">
     <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="AlphabetOnly" />
</telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Javascript:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function AlphabetOnly(sender, eventArgs)
{
    if (key==35 || key==36)
           return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where's the `key` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

if you catch the keycode **keydown** or **keyup** instead of **keypress**,

```
# returns 51, $ returns 52, End is 35 and home is 36
```

Comment: Thank you kennebec, but there's no event like 'keyup' or 'keydown' for the client-events under RadTextBox. :L

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this question is quite old, but I just ran across the same issue earlier today.
As a workaround, I'm also checking whether the shift key is pressed or not. On most keyboards, shift is required to enter the # or $ keys. So if shift is pressed than it's the symbol key, if not then it's the END/HOME key.

```
function checkKeyPress(evt) {
    if (evt.which === 35) {
        if (evt.shiftKey === true) {
            //'#' key
        } else {
            //'END' key
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with jQueryUI, you may use `$.ui.keyCode constants:`

```
keyCode: {

    END: 35,
    HOME: 36
}
```

So in order to check for HOME pressed use:

```
if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.HOME) { ... }
```

Comment: And how is this solving the problem? Can you exactly point a single issue you have solved here by dragging jQueryUI into the play?

Comment: @JanTuroň Since the "#" and "&" aren't defined in the keyCode list, it would solve the issue of grabbing those keys when END and HOME are the only ones desired.